# React Native iOS app closed immediately after opening react-native-contacts

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, crash

During the app external testing, got a very strange report from a client.
The app was immediately closed(crash, but without red screen) after user opened contacts screen. Contacts were shown for a second and then the app closed. I've tried to reproduce the problem multiple times, but no success.

Also, there's a crash log:
https://monosnap.com/file/aSp2omGZycXk9YujpE0xPFb4O5kJWX

What can be the problem? Maybe a crash in RN core?

Answer (score 0):

This could be mainly because of the memory overflow. Testing on simulator usually works since you have very few contacts on simulator. But when the app is installed on real devices, it's an expensive operation to load all the contacts into the memory and also render them in the list view at the same time.

Possible solution is to render the contacts that are only visible to the user on the screen and load the rest as the user scrolls down. This will reduce memory consumption and UI becomes very responsive. Flipkart has a very good implementation to overcome this problem. The library is known as [RecyclerListView](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview)